# $\exists L \in \Bbb{R}(\forall n \in \Bbb{N}(a^\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n\rfloor}{10^n} \leq L))$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let be $a \in \Bbb{R}^{>0}, b \in \Bbb{R}$, $\exists L \in \Bbb{R}(\forall n \in \Bbb{N}(a^\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n\rfloor}{10^n}\leq L ))$?

I thought: if $a=1 \to 1^\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n\rfloor}{10^n}=1\leq L$ therefore $1\leq 1=L$; but in the cases $a>1$ and $0<a<1$ I do not know continue, How can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze the exponent in function of n, try to see if it is bounded, ...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand!

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: ok.. $\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor \leq b \cdot 10^n$, therefore $\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}\leq b $ is it correct?

Comment: @Thomas.. aaah, if $a>1$ then $a^{\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}} < a^b$.. is correct? If $0<a<1$ then $\nexists L \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: @Soviet This is true if $a > 1$. If $0 < a < 1$ I think that $a^x < 1$ anyways know ?

Comment: @Soviet And know the case where b < 0...

Comment: one moment.. I have a problem, in my studies $a^b\doteq lim_{n \to \infty}a^{\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}}$, therefore I can't use $a^b$ in $a^{\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}} < a^b$... mmm

Comment: use $[b+1]$ instead of $b$

Comment: so if $ a>1 $ then $a^{\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}}<a^{\lfloor b+1 \rfloor}$ ?

Comment: yes. check for yourself ! :) Is $[b.10^n] <= ...$ ?

Comment: $\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor \leq \lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor +1 $.. is correct?

Comment: read yourself again please

Comment: if I proof by contradiction I have $\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor > \lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor +1$ therefore $\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor - \lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor=0 >1$.. it is absurd... then $\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor \leq \lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor +1$ yes?

Comment: ahhh I must to proof $\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}<\lfloor b +1 \rfloor$, is correct?

Comment: exactly ! else you are just proving that x < x+1 :)

Comment: pls show me the proof of $\frac{\lfloor b \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}<\lfloor b +1 \rfloor$, thanks in advance! :)